# Remove "Not Secure" Label from a Chromium Shortcut

Tags: networking, gnome, chrome

I have several local network websites that I have added to my favorites bar in GNOME. However, each of the apps have a bar at the top letting me know that my connection is insecure.

[image: Not Secure Report]

Things I have tried:

1. Adding `--disable-web-security` in the `~/.gnome/apps/` entry
2. Adding `--ignore-certificate-errors` in the `~/.gnome/apps/` entry
3. Adding both of the above steps to the `~/.gnome/apps/` entry

Entry for the RStudio Server App:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=RStudio
Exec=/usr/bin/chromium-browser --disable-web-security --profile-directory=Default --app-id=khgfkcndmdhfailppfibflpjmbbllooa --ignore-certificate-errors
Icon=chrome-khgfkcndmdhfailppfibflpjmbbllooa-Default
StartupWMClass=crx_khgfkcndmdhfailppfibflpjmbbllooa
OnlyShowIn=Old;
```

System Information:

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
- Chromium: 80.0.3987.149
- GNOME: 3.28.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "not secure" means the *site* your bookmark refers to doesn't offer secure connection options. Complain to the site's administrator to fix their configuration. Nothing you can do locally (and right so, just painting over the warning message doesn't fix anything).

Comment: I am the site administrator (it's my homelab), do you have a resource to fixing the configuration?